# What is the meaning of the double turnstile symbol ($\models$)?

Tags: logic, notation

What's the meaning of the double turnstile symbol in logic or mathematical notation? :

> $\models$

Comment: Voting to close as "too localized".

Comment: Add '\models' and 'latex' and it could be a useful question. Compare current google results for those two terms.

Comment: @Harry: Not too localised, if any model-theory questions are not too localised.

Comment: As a general comment, I recommend using detexify (http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) and Wikipedia to help first.

Comment: @Akhil Mathew: Detexify is very useful. Thanks.

Comment: The value is limited as we can't exactly search for this question

Comment: @Casebash: searching for 'models' gives this page as the top result. Although now that the question has been fully answered, I don't mind closure.

Comment: @Casebash: Why not edit the title to "what is the meaning of the 'double turnstile' symbol in logic?" ?

Comment: @Tom: That would be better

Comment: I voted to re-open, since I don't understand why it was closed in the first place.

Comment: It's also used in the topic of Functional Dependencies in Database Design

Comment: Came here looking for the historical origin of the turnstiles. Found it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turnstile_%28symbol%29

Comment: approach0 can now be used to find this question

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Just to enlarge on Harry's answer:

Your symbol denotes one of two specified notions of implication in formal logic

$\vdash$ -the **turnstile** symbol denotes **syntactic** implication (syntactic here means  related to syntax, the structure of a sentence), where the 'algebra' of the logical system in play (for example [sentential calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentential_calculus)) allows us to 'rearrange and cancel' the stuff we know on the left into the thing we want to prove on the right.

An example might be the classic "all men are mortal $\wedge$ socrates is a man $\vdash$ socrates is mortal" ('$\wedge$' of course here just means 'and'). You can almost imagine cancelling out the 'man bit' on the left to just give the sentence on the right (although the truth may be more complex...).

---

$\models$ -the **double turnstile**, on the other hand, is not so much about algebra as meaning (formally it denotes **semantic** implication)- it means that any interpretation of the stuff we know on the left must have the corresponding interpretation of the thing we want to prove on the right true.

An example would be if we had an infinite set of sentences: $\Gamma$:= {"1 is lovely", "2 is lovely", ...} in which all numbers appear, and the sentence A= " the natural numbers are precisely {1,2,...}" listing all numbers. Any interpretation would give us B="all natural numbers are lovely". So $\Gamma$, A $\models$ B.

---

Now, the goal of any logician trying to set up a formal system is to have $\Gamma \vdash A \iff \Gamma \models A$, meaning that the 'algebra' must line up with the interpretation, and this is not something we can take as given. Take the second example above- can we be sure that algebraic operations can 'parse' those infinitely many sentences and make the simple sentence on the right?? (this is to do with a property called **compactness**)

The goal can be split into two distinct subgoals:

**Soundness:** $A \vdash B \Rightarrow A \models B$

**Completeness:** $A \models B \Rightarrow A \vdash B$

Where the first stops you proving things that aren't true when we interpret them and the second means that everything we know to be true on interpretation, we must be able to prove.

Sentential calculus, for example, can be proved complete (and was in Godel's lesser known, but celebrated completeness theorem), but for other systems Godel's incompleteness theorem, give us a terrible choice between the two.

---

**In summary:** The interplay of meaning and axiomatic machine mathematics, captured by the difference between $\models$ and $\vdash$, is a subtle and interesting thing.

Comment: Gosh, wrote a lot more than I intended there, but it is jolly interesting... now can someone please tell me how to fix my Tex!?

Comment: TeX fixed - see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/692/tex-implies-symbol-does-not-work

Comment: @TomBoardman Thank you for your answer but think it can be more complete if you also explained about the meaning of double turnstile in different contexts, as explained in "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_turnstile". (Showing tautology, sastisfaction and semantic consequence)

Comment: About the $\vDash$ example. How can "any interpretation" be correct? If I interpret some words differently, it can become nonsense (for example an interpretation where "precisely" means "not"). But I'm not sure if I understand the underlying concepts.

Comment: this is a rather vague explanation

Answer (score 6):

$\models$ is also known as the [satisfication relation](https://planetmath.org/SatisfactionRelation). For a structure $\mathcal{M}=(M,I)$ and an $\mathcal{M}$-assignment $\nu$, $(\mathcal{M},\nu)\models \varphi$ means that the formula $\varphi$ is true with the particular assignment $\nu$.
See http://www.trinity.edu/cbrown/topics_in_logic/struct/node2.html

Comment: Are you ever coming back? Just curious... :)

Comment: Are you coming back anytime soon?

Answer (score 5):

It is a symbol from model theory denoting [entailment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entailment).

A ⊧ B is read as "A entails B".

Answer (score 3):

It is called a 'double turnstile': http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_turnstile.

Comment: Sorry, I realise that I haven't actually answered your question (about the meaning). I've seen it used in logic to stand for semantic entailment, but I imagine it has other uses.

Comment: @bryn: Not that I've seen.  Forcing uses two vertical lines.

Comment: As a related question, what does the 'single turnstile' mean? I've seen it plenty of times.

Comment: Is it equivalent toe the single or double tailed right-arrows in logic?

Comment: @Noldorin, perhaps the simplest example of the distinction could be seen in classical propositional logic.

A statement like |= p -> (q -> p) means that the no matter the truth values of p and q, the value of p -> (q -> p) is always truth (which can be seen by looking at the truth table). 

A statement like |- p -> (q -> p) means that we can prove this formula purely by using axioms/rules of deduction, with no mention of truth or meaning.

Incidentally, I think you could ask this as a separate question on the site, since we don't want the comment strand to be where one has to look for answers.