# Meaning of symbols $\vdash$ and $ \models$

Tags: logic, notation, meta-math

I'm confused about the use of symbols $\vdash$ and  $ \models$. Reading the answers to
[Notation Question: What does $\vdash$ mean in logic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280384/notation-question-what-does-vdash-mean-in-logic?rq=1)
and
[What is the meaning of the double turnstile symbol ($\models$)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-double-turnstile-symbol-models)
I see that:

the **turnstile** symbol $ \vdash $ denotes syntactic implication. Then $ S \vdash \psi$ means that $\psi$ can be derived from the formulae in $S$

the **double turnstile** $ \models $, denotes semantic implication. Then the notation $A \models B$ means simply that B is true in every model in which A is true.

So I understand that, e.g., $(ZFC+ A) \vdash B$ means that $A \Rightarrow B$ is a theorem in ZFC and, in this sense $\vdash$ is a *mathematical* symbol for a theorem. While $(ZFC+ A) \models B$ means that $ B$ is true in every model of ZFC in which $A$ is true, and, in this sense $\models$ is not a mathematical but a *metamathematical* symbol. 
I understand correctly? And those are the only uses of the two symbols?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are right in your definitions, but both symbols can be used in the *metatheory*, meaning that they are used to describe properties and relations between objects of the theory : axioms, theorems, and between the theory and its models.

With a formal theory, like $\mathsf {ZFC}$ or $\mathsf {PA}$, based on first-order logic, it is useful to separate symbols of the language, like :

- $\lnot, \rightarrow, \land, \lor$, all belonging to the common first-order language
- $\in$, specific of set theory
- $+$, specific of arithmetic,

and symbols used in the meta-language, like :

- $\vdash$, for the relation of *derivability* in a theory, meaning there is a formal derivation of a theorem from the axioms of the theory
- $\vDash$, for the relation of *logical consequence*, meaning that a sentence in the language of the theory is true in all models of the theory, i.e. in all interpretations satisfying the axioms.

The two relations are linked through [Gödel's completeness theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem).

---

*Expanded edition*

The above is a précis of the "standard view", dating back to the '50s and '60s of last century; see :

- Stephen Cole Kleene, [Introduction to metamathematics](https://books.google.it/books?id=HZAjPwAACAAJ) (1952), page 87 :

> We introduce, by a metamathematical definition, the notion of "formal deducibility under assumptions". Given a list $D_1, \ldots, D_l$ of (occurrences of) formulas, a finite sequence of one or more (occurrences of) formulas is called a (*formal*) *deduction from* the *assumptions formulas* $D_1, \ldots, D_l$, if each formula of the sequence is either one of the formulas $D_1, \ldots, D_l$, or an axiom, or an immediate consequence of preceding formulas of the sequence. A deduction is said to be a deduction *of* its last formula $E$; and this formula is said to be *deducible from* the assumption formulas (in symbols, $D_1, \ldots, D_l \vdash E$), and is called the *conclusion* of the deduction. (The symbol "$\vdash$" may be read "yields".)

See also :

- Stephen Cole Kleene, [Mathematical logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=4GzCAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA26) (1967), page 26 :

> we define : $B$ is a *valid consequence* of $A_1, \ldots, A_m$, or in symbols $A_1, \ldots, A_m \vDash B$, if, [...] the formula $B$ is *true* in all those [structures] in which $A_1, \ldots, A_m$ are simultaneously *true*. The symbol $\vDash$ may be read "entails".

And see footnote, page 36 :

> The symbol "$\vdash$" goes back to Frege ([Begriffsschrift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begriffsschrift#The_calculus_in_Frege.27s_work), 1879); the present use of it to Rosser (1935) and Kleene (1934). [...] The parallel use of "$\vDash$" is perhaps original with Kleene (1956).

---

See Rob's comment below ; the *sequent calculus* ([Gentzen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerhard_Gentzen), 1934) is a formalization of the *derivability* relation. The original Gentzen's syntax for *sequents* :

> $\Gamma \rightarrow \Delta$

is often written with $\vdash$ in place of the auxiliary symbol $\rightarrow$ (or sometimes : $\Longrightarrow$).

Comment: Yes, that is the standard usage in a lot of the logic literature. But it is worth noting that $\vdash$ is standard notation in connection with sequent calculi and type theory as an object language construct, with $\Gamma \vdash A$ being syntax for the assertion that formula $A$ holds in some context $\Gamma$ of assumptions or variable declarations. (Object language $\vdash$ and meta-language $\vdash$ may then be related by some form of the deduction theorem.)

Answer (score 5):

Both symbols are either mathematical or metamathematical.

If you work in a universe admitting semantics for first-order logic, then $\models$ is a statement about a theory and a sentence, as well $\vdash$ is a statement about a theory and a sentence. Since theories and sentences are mathematical objects, this is a mathematical statement.

If you work internally in a model of $\sf ZFC$ and say that $\sf ZFC+\varphi\vdash\psi$, as a metamathematical statement, then you really say that the metatheory proves that there is a proof etc. etc.

As a side note, $\models$ is also used as a satisfaction relation between a structure and a sentence, not just theories and sentences.

Answer (score 2):

It may be confusing because we make statements about ZFC while working in ZFC, but both are mathematical in the following sense:

Define $\mathrm{ZFC}=\{\varphi_e, \varphi_i,\varphi_c,\ldots\}$ as a set of formulas (i.e. sequences of letters) representing the usual axioms (extensionality, infinity, choice, ...).

A model of this $\mathrm{ZFC}$ is just a pair $M=(A,\in)$ of a set and a binary relation on $A$ satisfying the formulas in $\mathrm{ZFC}$ according to Tarski's definition of truth, the notation for this is $M\models\mathrm{ZFC}$.

We say $\mathrm{ZFC}$ satisfies a formula $\psi$ if for all models $M$ of $\mathrm{ZFC}$ we have $M\models \psi$. Again we just check if $\psi$ holds in $M$ according to the definition of truth. This is denoted $\mathrm{ZFC}\models\psi$, using the same symbol for something different.

On the other hand, we say that $\mathrm{ZFC}$ proves $\psi$, if we can derive $\psi$ from the axioms of logic, the formulas in $\mathrm{ZFC}$, and inference rules such as modus ponens. This is just a formal manipulation of symbols of various formulas and is denoted $\mathrm{ZFC}\vdash\psi$.

There's an amazing result called the completeness theorem (for first order logic) that for any theory $T$ (again just a set of formulas) and any formula $\psi$, we have $T\models\psi$ if and only if $T\vdash\psi$. Note that the "if" part is trivial.

Comment: I was wondering what is A made of (in M above). Is it made of formulas of ZFC ? For completeness, isn’t it T ⊨ s implies T ⊢ s ? I had read somewhere we have soundness when T ⊢ s implies T ⊨ s (which intuitively looks OK to me): if completeness means ⊨ if and only if ⊢, then completeness cannot come without soundness, and I had read it is not the case (not always).

Answer (score 0):

"So I understand that, e.g., (ZFC+A)⊢B means that A⇒B is a theorem in ZFC and, in this sense ⊢ is a mathematical symbol for a theorem."

No.  (ZFC+A)⊢B means that given ZFC and A, B is provable. (A⇒B) may not be provable, if say the Deduction Meta-Theorem does not hold for the system.

To illustrate the difference between the two symbols, suppose we have a system which has only one axiom: CCpqCCqrCpr and the only rule of inference is condensed detachment, and has semantics captured by the following matrix with "0" standing for falsity, and "1" for truth:

```
C  0  1
0  1  1
1  0  1
```

It holds that CCpqCCqrCpr $ \models $ CpCqp, since whenever CCpqCCqrCpr is true, so is CpCqp.  However, CCpqCCqrCpr $\vdash$ CpCqp is not true, since we can't prove CpCqp from *just* CCpqCCqrCpr under the rule of condensed detachment.

Comment: but... the deduction theorem is not valid for all deductive systems?

Comment: @EmilioNovati - as Doug's example shows, in principle **not** necessarily a deductive system has a *Deduction Th*; of course, **all** systems we currently use in order to formalize math theories have it...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA That's not exactly true.  Some people have tried to work out a set theory with relevant logic as a background.  There is also fuzzy subset theory, which has infinite-valued logic as a background.  Neither have the Deduction Meta-Theorem (in the sense that if $\gamma$, $\alpha$ $\vdash$ $\beta$, then $\gamma$ $\vdash$ C $\alpha$ $\beta$ is a meta-theorem).