# For finite $\Sigma$, if $\Sigma \vdash A$ then $\Sigma \models A$

Tags: logic

In my book I have a theorem called "Soundness theorem" and it says:

> For finite set $\Sigma$, if $\Sigma \vdash A$ then $\Sigma  \models A$

Can someone tell me what the symbol $\vdash$ and the symbol $\models$ means?

Comment: See this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1115066/meaning-of-symbols-vdash-and-models).

Answer (score 4):

The first is a syntatic notion, the second semantic:

- $\Gamma ⊢ \varphi$ means that there is a derivation $\mathcal{D}$ from hypothesis in $\Gamma$ and with conclusion $\varphi$.
- $\Gamma ⊨ \varphi$ means that any model $\mathcal{M}$ of $\Gamma$ makes $\varphi$ true.

Roughly, the [soundness theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundness) says that the inference rules of logic system don't prove falsities.