# What are the meanings of the various turnstiles

Tags: logic, notation

It is easy to find the meanings of $\vdash$ and $\models$ (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-double-turnstile-symbol-models) and Wikipedia) but what of the (triple?) turnstile $\Vvdash$ and the (vertical double?) turnstile $\Vdash$? Do they have a standard accepted meaning and usage?

(It seems implausible that no exhaustive index of all these symbols already exists but I couldn't find one)

Comment: For $\Vdash$, see [Kripke semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kripke_semantics) : it is the relation of *satisfaction* between nodes $w \in W$ and modal formulas : $w \Vdash \varphi$.

Comment: @Mauro:  Forcing too.

Answer (score 2):

According to Change/Keisler, "Model theory", 3rd edition, page 209, the double vertical bar turnstile means the "finite forcing relation". The detailed explanation is somewhat technical.

PS. Much the same definition for the double vertical turnstile is given by Smullyan/Fitting, "Set theory and the continuum problem", page 210. They say that $p\Vdash X$ means "$p$ forces $X$".

PPS. Jech, "The axiom of choice", page 202, says $p\Vdash\phi$ means "$p$ forces $\phi$".

PPPS. Huth/Ryan, "Logic in computer science", page 310, says $x\Vdash\phi$ means "$x$ satisfies $\phi$" or "$\phi$ is true in world $x$". So far I haven't found any triple vertical bars.

PPPPS. Curry, "Foundations of mathematical logic", pages 185–186, uses the double vertical turnstile, but his explanation of its meaning is totally incomprehensible.

PPPPPS. My other 40 books on mathematical logic and model theory don't use the double vertical turnstile, and none of them use the triple vertical turnstile. So I imagine it's not in common use.

Comment: Please read carefully the compiled version of your answer.

Comment: Whoops. I misread the TeXbook. What's the TeX symbol for double vertical turnstile?

Comment: `\Vdash` you mean?

Comment: Thanks for that. The Vdash symbol isn't in my old TeX book. But Vdash is what's used in HTML entities. So that sounds logical. I'll look around and see if there's an index of TeX notations on this web site somewhere.